# Facebook Drupal (fboauth) popup opening as full screen

Tags: facebook, drupal, popup

I am using Drupal fboauth module for Facebook connect. When I click on login button it should open a dialog popup box for authenticating application but instead it is showing in full browser view.[image: Please see screenshot attached]

As per documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/ I have also given param of display=popup but still it is showing in full browser view. This is happening for all browsers.

Any help much appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had the "[External Links](https://www.drupal.org/project/extlink)" module enabled. It saw the facebook url as external, and promptly added target="_blank", causing all clicks to open in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

> As per documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/ I have also given param of display=popup but still it is showing in full browser view.

Quote from there:

> *In 'popup' mode, the OAuth dialog is displayed in a form suitable for embedding in a popup window.*

The sole purpose of this parameter is to modify the appearance of the login dialog so that it is suitable for fitting into a smaller popup window, as opposed to being displayed in a “full” page.

This parameter does *not* trigger the opening of a popup – if you want the URL to be opened in a popup, you have to do that yourself. (And handle it’s closing after successful authentication yourself as well.)

Your other option is using `FB.login` from the JavaScript SDK – that will take care of opening and closing the popup for you.

Comment: Popup was working previously with same param, recently it stopped working. I don't know how.

Comment: It is probably something that changed on Facebook's side. I.e. the default is now opening a new window, and you need to pass a parameter to overwrite that behaviour. I'm bust trying to figure out where exactly in FBOAuth you do that.